# Windows XP reinstall, now I am unable to connect to broadband what shall I select to do this?

Tags: windows-xp, broadband

My hardrive was failing so I needed to reinstall Windows XP.  I completed the reinstall and the drivers but now only the wireless connection works.  The broadband states connected but does not go out to the Internet.

When I click Internet Explorer it says unable to find webpage. I have tried several major sites so I know it's not the site but some configuration or something I need to do on my end.

When I go to the command prompt and renew the IP address it refers to my wireless, nothing about this broadband connection.  What do I type/select to get this to go out to the Internet.  The broadband is working for my other laptop so I know the connection is not the issue.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install your ethernet drivers. If your ethernet port is on your motherboard, your motherboard manufacturer should have drivers for it on their site/disc.

If you use a PCI or PCIe card for ethernet connectivity, you'll need to install the drivers from that manufacturer.

Comment: I have the cd's from Dell resource for reinstallation of Drivers on the Dell Inspiron 1501 laptop and these are the choices that I have already installed.  
Broadcom 440x 10/100 Integrated Controller Rev: AO2
Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN MiniCard Rev: A17
Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN MiniCard Rev: A17
Dell Wireless 1490 Dual-Band WLAN MiniCard Rev A17
Dell Wireless 1505 Draft 802.11n WLAN Mini-Card Rev A17